# phpUnit phone number function failure

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following function to validate a phone number by its length.  When I pass a phone number 111-111-111 and echo its length it returns 10.  However, the phpUnit I wrote below to test this fails every time when it should pass.  I cannot figure out why this happening.  it does work without the hyphens.

```
function validatePhone($phone) {
    //eliminate every char except 0-9
    $justNums = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $phone);
    return((strlen($justNums) == 10) or (strlen($justNums) == 7));
}

public function testValidatePhoneGoodNumber() {
    $this->assertTrue($this->val->validatePhone(111-111-1111));  //THIS FAILS
}

public function testValidatePhoneGoodNumber() {
    $this->assertTrue($this->val->validatePhone(1111111111));  //THIS PASSES
}
```

Comment: I don't like regEx to simple examples, why don't just: `$justNums = str_replace('-', '', $phone);` ?

Comment: You're right.  I have been reading that regEx has a lot of overhead, especially for simple solutions like this.  I changed it to your example, but it still doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. Same results.

Comment: I'm no familiar with phpUnit but, shouldn't the parameter with dashes be quoted? like: `$this->assertTrue($this->val->validatePhone('111-111-1111'));` otherwise you were sending the number `-1111` only, and well, it's not 10 neither 7 characters long.

Comment: Wow, you're right!  Thanks a ton.  I'm a bit new to php, would have taken me some time to figure that out.  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add solved to the title, instead either select a correct answer or submit your own answer to your question for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes to input that is of a php mixed pseudo-type.

```
function validatePhone($phone) {
//eliminate every char except 0-9
$justNums = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $phone);
return((strlen($justNums) == 10) or (strlen($justNums) == 7));
```

}

```
public function testValidatePhoneGoodNumber() {
$this->assertTrue($this->val->validatePhone('111-111-1111'));
```

}